# How to include a file in the root of boot.img?

Tags: android, linux

I'm now compiling boot.img from android source tree, and I want to include a file in the root of boot.img(root directory of boot partition), where should I put the file before making the boot.img?

(Actually I am doing something following the blog https://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2014/05/using-kitkat-verified-boot.html#!/2014/05/using-kitkat-verified-boot.html , where there is one step: Once you have converted the key, include it in the root of your boot image under the verity_key filename. )

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you don't need to place the verity_key in root dir by hand, what you need to do just replace the verity_key which location is ANDROID_SRC/build/target/product/security/verity_key.

And then the Android.mk in the same dir will copy the verity_key to $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT), try to "make bootimage", and then the Android build system will include verity_key into boot.img.

In fact, the ramdisk.img include the verity_key, and boot.img include the ramdisk.img.